# Import Images/Pictures from a Closed Excel Workbook using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, image, import, adodb

I am copying csv files and pictures from a network folder into different sheets of a `temporary Excel workbook`. I use this `temporary workbook` to `slice/dice the csv data` and `resize the pictures` placed in a sheet.

I want to import these pictures from this `CLOSED temporary workbook` into my `current Workbook` OR import the `complete Sheet` into my `current Workbook`. I am able to import all the other sheets containing csv textual data with `ADODB recordset`, but cannot import the pictures.

- Is there a way to import these pictures `without opening the temporary workbook`?
- Does ADO have a `method to import pictures` embedded in Excel worksheet cells of a closed Excel Workbook?
- Is there some picture control in Excel to which all the images can be initially stored in the temporary workbook and later imported back into my current workbook?
- Is there a way to import/copy the image sheet from the `closed temporary workbook` into `current workbook`?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to extract the pictures without opening the file.

Comment: thanks for confirming @TimWilliams. So there maybe only 1 way to do it, i.e. Workbooks.Open(fullfiname). Select Image sheet and then loop and copy the shapes to my current workbook. Also, I want to know, Is there a way to persist a session as long as my current workbook is open? i.e. insert the pictures to the temporary workbook sheet, resize them and then also collect them into say, a dictionary or a class object, then import the images from the class or dictionary to my current workbook, whenever i need them?

Answer (score 0):

Where are the pictures coming from originally.  I'm guessing they are not originally coming from Excel, right.  I certainly don't know your full setup, but if you have a bunch of images in a folder, and you want to import all into an Excel worksheet, you can use the code below to do just that.

```
Sub InsertPics()
Dim fPath As String, fName As String
Dim r As Range, rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
fPath = "C:\your_path\"
Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
i = 1
For Each r In rng
    fName = Dir(fPath)
    Do While fName <> ""
            With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(fPath & fName)
                .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                Set px = .ShapeRange
                If .ShapeRange.Width > Rows(i).Columns(2).Width Then .ShapeRange.Width = Columns(2).Width
                    With Cells(i, 2)
                        px.Top = .Top
                        px.Left = .Left
                        .RowHeight = px.Height
                    End With
            End With
            i = i + 1
        fName = Dir
    Loop
Next r
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Ash, I am already importing the pictures from a network folder into a temporary Excel file. Now, I want to reimport those images from this temporary Excel workbook into my current Excel workbook (thisworkbook) without opening it. I am thinking of something like an ado stream object, but never used it.

Comment: Why do you need the intermediate step?  I know you can import data from ranges in a closed workbook.  See the link below for all details.  

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win024.htm  

I'm not sure you can import images from a closed workbook.  This doesn't seem like a good approach.